# R: Ordering specific vars in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with variables Alpha thru Zulu, but not in any particular order (e.g. Bravo, Yankee, Charlie, etc). I want to alphabetically order vars Delta thru Whiskey (20 vars), and leave the rest as they are.

e.g. unordered DF colnames (before operation): `Zulu, Bravo, Alpha, Delta, Kilo, Tango, .... Whiskey, Yankee, X-Ray`

e.g. ordered DF colnames (after operation): `Zulu, Bravo, Alpha, #Start ordered section# Delta, Echo, Fox, Golf, .... Whiskey, #End ordered section# Yankee, X-Ray`

I think I'm close using the `order` command, but am missing something...

`DF <- DF[ , order( which(names(DF) == 'Delta') : which(names(mitch) == 'Whiskey')) ]`

Comment: Can you provide an example. Since the variables are not in any particular order, once you order a subset, its not clear what you mean by leave the rest as they are?

Lets say its from "a" to "g" -> f,c,a,d,e,b,g
You want to sort from b to f, so how should the final order look like?

Comment: Added an example, which hopefully is illustrative. Using your example: `f,c,a,d,e,b,l,k,m,r,g` becomes `f,c,a,d,e,b,g,k,l,m,r`. That first vector of columns (`f-e`) stays the same, but `b` thru `g` becomes `b` thru `r` with `g` in its proper alphabetical position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

```
# Create list of variables to sort
names.DF <- names(DF)

# Find just the variables between the 4th variable ('Delta') and the 23rd variable ('Whiskey') 
ord <- names.DF %in% sort(names.DF)[(which(names.DF=='Delta')):(which(names.DF=='Whiskey'))]

# Replace just the desired variables with the properly sorted variables
names.DF[ord] <- sort(names.DF[ord])

# Use the sorted list to sort the variables in the dataframe
DF <- DF[,names.DF]
```

This solution will order the variables as you want.  It can also handle the situation where Alpha, Bravo, Charlie, X-ray, Yankee, and Zulu are mixed in with the variables you want ordered, instead of just at either end. For instance,

`Zulu, Alpha, X-ray, Echo, Whiskey, Delta, Golf, Bravo, Charlie, Yankee`

becomes

`Zulu, Alpha, X-ray, Delta, Echo, Golf, Whiskey, Bravo, Charlie, Yankee`

and

`Echo, Zulu, Whiskey, Delta, Alpha, X-ray, Bravo, Charlie, Golf, Yankee`

becomes

`Delta, Zulu, Echo, Golf, Alpha, X-ray, Bravo, Charlie, Whiskey, Yankee`

Comment: I'm getting an error `argument length of 0` when I try the second line of code... there must be a problem w/ my dataset.

Comment: Is it possible that `'Delta'` and `'Whiskey'` don't match exactly?  Different case, for instance, or different spelling?  You could use `[(which(toupper(names.DF)=='DELTA')):(which(toupper(names.DF)=='WHISKEY'))]`, or just substitute that portion with [4:23] if you know that you want to use the 4th and 23rd ordered variable out of 26.